# allow cross origin request for laravel route on nginx

Tags: laravel, http, nginx, cross-domain

I want to access a laravel 5.5 api endpoint `https://foo.bar.com/api/v1.0/foo/bar` from another origin. Thus I need to allow cross origin requests. I've added the header to my nginx config. Yet my browser still complains about it not being present.
This is my nginx config:

```
server {
   listen       *:443 ssl;

   server_name  foo.bar.com ;
   ssl on;

   ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/nxv_bhxwewp1idzm.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/nxv_bhxwewp1idzm.key;
   ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
   ssl_session_timeout       5m;
   ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers               "...";
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   client_max_body_size 1m;
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;

   access_log            /var/log/nginx/ssl-nxv_bhxwewp1idzm.access.log;
   error_log             /var/log/nginx/ssl-nxv_bhxwewp1idzm.error.log;


   root /var/www/share/foo.bar.com;
   location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {


     set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
     root  /var/www/share/foo.bar.com/public/;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

   }
   location / {

    root  /var/www/share/foo.bar.com/public/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    autoindex off;
    index  index.html index.php;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';


   }
   sendfile off;
 }
```

Comment: As far as I know PHP is responsibe for its own headers. You could use https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors

Comment: That's not entirely true, you can configure the web server to handle CORS or PHP can do the work. The benefit of using the web server is you don't have to boot the Laravel application just to generate a CORS response. Here is a good [configuration for nginx](https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already took the info from the link @DigitalDrifter has posted. But it seems just adding the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` isn't enough to get it to work. Although I don't care about access methods and such.
So this got the deal working:

```
server {
   listen       *:443 ssl;

   server_name  foo.bar.com ;
   ssl on;

   ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/nxv_bhxwewp1idzm.crt;
   ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/nxv_bhxwewp1idzm.key;
   ssl_session_cache         shared:SSL:10m;
   ssl_session_timeout       5m;
   ssl_protocols             TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
   ssl_ciphers               "...";
   ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
   client_max_body_size 1m;
     index  index.html index.htm index.php;

   access_log            /var/log/nginx/ssl-nxv_bhxwewp1idzm.access.log;
   error_log             /var/log/nginx/ssl-nxv_bhxwewp1idzm.error.log;


   root /var/www/share/foo.bar.com;
   location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {


     set $path_info $fastcgi_path_info;
     root  /var/www/share/foo.bar.com/public/;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
     add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
     add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';

     fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

   }
   location / {

    root  /var/www/share/foo.bar.com/public/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    autoindex off;
    index  index.html index.php;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'X-Frame-Options' 'ALLOW-FROM *';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';


   }
   sendfile off;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

add both lines into below file

> /etc/nginx/sites-available/yours_conf_file

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Content-Type';
```

and restart nginx server

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```